# show parameters in the log DataStage Cloud

Tags: cloud, stage, datastage, hierarchical

DATASTAGE Cloud, how can I display, in the log, the value of a parameter with link value of an input the stage hierarchical ?

I want to execute a web services POST with the value input parameter equal to a link value.
Thanks